# Visual Basic - Saving and editing excel forms

Tags: vb.net

I have run into a bug.
I am trying to create a program which creates, loads and saves excel files. I am only using Visual Basic so please do not answer with other languages.

The program is meant to create an excel file called "Example" or load it if it already exists.

```
        If (My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("D:\Programming\Example.xlsx")) Then
        xlWorkBook.Save()
    Else
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Filename:="D:\Programming\Example.xlsx",
        FileFormat:=51)
    End If
```

For some reason, it does not seem to do this and instead creates a file called "book1.xlsx" instead of "Example.xlsx".

Also when it saves it seems to keep excel open in the background.
This is my full code:

```html
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Create_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Create.Click
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

        xlApp.Visible = True

        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        With xlWorkSheet
            .Range("A1").Value = "Month"
            .Range("A2").Value = "January"
            .Range("A3").Value = "February"
            .Range("A4").Value = "March"
            .Range("A5").Value = "April"

            .Range("B1").Value = "Loan Repayment"
            .Range("B2").Value = "1000.00"
            .Range("B3").Value = "1200.00"
            .Range("B4").Value = "1300.00"
            .Range("B5").Value = "1600.00"

            .Range("A6").Value = "Total Paid"

            .Range("B6").Formula = "=Sum(B2:B5)"
        End With

        Test.Text = xlWorkSheet.Range("A1").Value

    End Sub

    Private Sub Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
        If (My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("D:\Programming\Example.xlsx")) Then
            xlWorkBook.Save()
        Else
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Filename:="D:\Programming\Example.xlsx",
            FileFormat:=51)
        End If

        xlWorkBook.Close()

        xlApp.Quit()

        ReleaseAll(xlApp)
        ReleaseAll(xlWorkBook)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReleaseAll(ByVal obj As Object)

        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing

        Catch ex As Exception

            obj = Nothing

        Finally

            GC.Collect()

        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Cheers appreciate any help. :D

Comment: If you want VB.NET answers you should probably check your tags...

Comment: I don't want VB.NET answers VBA and VB.NET are totally different. I have tagged it with VBA and specifically said I want it with VBA. @t

Comment: The code in the question isn't VBA. `Try/Catch/Finally` doesn't exist in VBA. `Handles` doesn't exist in VBA. `Imports` doesn't exist in VBA

Comment: Sorry, my bad. @barrowc

Comment: You specifically said "Visual Basic", which typically means VB.NET, and your code is VB.NET, as @barrowc points out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was coming about because I was creating multiple instances of the same Workbook instead of opening it if the file was already existing.

This fixes the code:

```
        If (My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Application.StartupPath + "\Book1.xlsx")) Then
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbook.Open(Application.StartupPath + "\Book1.xlsx")
    Else
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    End If
```

However this creates another problem. The error says:

```
System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'Workbook' on type 'ApplicationClass' not found.'
```

In the line to open the workbook. (ln 15).